# WIX: How can I uninstall an ISAPI filter using WIX?

Tags: iis, wix, isapi

In WIX, I can install an ISAPI filter using the [iis:WebFilter](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_webfilter.htm) element:

```
<Component Id='C.Filter1' Guid="6781xxxx-xxxx-4893-xxxx-aaaabbbbdddd">
  <!-- CreateFolder - included to avoid problem with missing KeyPath -->
  <CreateFolder/>
  <iis:WebFilter Id="WebFilter1"
                 LoadOrder="first"
                 Name="My Custom ISAPI Filter"
                 Path="[INSTALLDIR]\Filter.dll"
                 WebSite='SelectedWebSite'
                 />
</Component>
```

When I run the resulting MSI, it installs the given ISAPI filter in the given website.

How can I *remove*  or *unconfigure* that filter on uninstall of the MSI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake.  I had inadvertently set SKIPCONFIGUREIIS on uninstall, and so the filter was not uninstalled.

When I fixed the condition, it worked as expected.